# Hide Title column links in the print out

Tags: 2013, hyperlink, sharepoint-on-prem, printing

In a custom list view, we are using Title(Linked to item with edit menu) or the the Title (linked to item) columns. However when the list is printed it shows the underlying links/urls in addition to the column text. To prevent this we are using the plain Title column, but this is not the permanent solution. We would like to use one of the the hyperlinked Title columns, but don't want to see the urls/links for the text. Is there a CSS solution for this?

Comment: What if you formatted your links to look like text. They would still work, and they would print like text. Example: `.ms-vb-title a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}`

Comment: @JamesFlattery Thank you for responding, but this is not about formatting at all. The actual url behind the hyperlink text is displayed in the print out , which otherwise doesn't show up on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media print CSS does the trick.

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```